# Run stored procedure as administrator

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use the following code to run a stored procedure `dbo.UPDATE_ELECTRICAL_CABLES_TD_FROM_QC`:

```
public void RunUpdateElectricalCablesSPS()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("data source=HUSSEIN******;initial catalog=GASCODB;Trusted_Connection = yes"))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.UPDATE_ELECTRICAL_CABLES_TD_FROM_QC", conn)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
    { 
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The stored procedure updates a SQL Server table from an Excel sheet.

When I run the code, it fails with following message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server (null)"
> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" returned message "Unspecified error"

When I run the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio using administrator credentials, it runs without problems, otherwise it fails.

So how can I connect to the database using administrator credentials to run the stored procedure? Or if the problem has different cause, help fixing it.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: That error *normally* means that the file you were trying to access doesn't exist (or can't be accessed).

Comment: ACE OLEDB provider is not actually supported by SQL Server, because it's a GUI-based provider. It works, sort of, but no support from Microsoft. I suggest you use another method to access Excel files, such as Powershell or C# or VBA

Comment: Can't you run the application as the admin user? this should then forward the user token if you use trusted connection. Your whole solution sounds pretty weird though, if you already have a C# why bother with a procedure that does things to an excel? This is like calling uber just to change a channel on your tv

Answer (score 2):

The naive/simple option is changing the connection string to replace `Trusted Connection=yes` with your admin credentials. However, be aware this means leaving those administrator credentials embedded in the code... not very safe.

The better option is logging into the server with Management Studio and granting your user account the permissions it needs.

In this case, that means granting your user the ability to use a certain linked server, or configuring the initial SQL Server to use appropriate credentials for the remote linked server when your user is making the connection.

Finally, we can't see the stored procedure, but the fact we see `(null)` for the name of the linked server tells us the procedure may be doing some other work first to find what connection to use, and this fails for your user account. In that case, you will also need to make sure this step can succeed. Seeing the provider is for MS Access/Excel, it's possibly looking up a file name based on the user, and your account doesn't have a record indicating what file you want.